# Java - How to compare elements in a list created from a split string

Tags: java, string, list, split

I need to see if any of the words in a very long string were the word "the" (then count how many times this happened)
so I split the string into individual elements of a list

```
String [ ] list1 = phrase1.split(" ");
```

How can I compare the individual elements of the list with the string "the"?

With an array I would use

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
 {
   if (string[i].equals("the"))
   {
     count++;
   }
}

return count;
```

But, you can't call and element in a list like that. What do I do?

Can I use the equals method with lists?

**EDIT:**
I tried to apply the answers I received as follows

```
static public int countWordsEqualTo( String [ ] list, int wordcount, String wordsearch)
    {
        int count = 0;
        String[] list1 = list.split(" ");
        for(String word: list1)
        {
            if (word.equals(wordsearch))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

It will not compile. What did I do wrong?

Comment: so the problem here is to compare each item in the list named **list1** with the string "the"?

Comment: replace "string" with "list1", in your code

Comment: But `list1` IS an array.  What is the problem here?

Comment: yes, I need to compare each item in the list with the string "the"

Comment: Answering your edit - you need to change that method signature - remove the `[ ]` before `list`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I need the [ ]before list because I am calling an array of strings

Comment: So, if you've already split your big long string into an array, then remove the line `String[] list1 = list.split(" ");` from the method, and just iterate across `list` in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modified for loop for both arrays and lists

```
String[] list1 = phrase1.split(" "); 

int count = 0;
for (String item : list1)
 {
   if (item.equals("the"))
   {
     count++;
   }
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use `equals` with lists but not the way you mean or want. Besides, you have a `String[]`, an array of strings, rather than a `List<String>` (list of strings).

What you do want to do is *iterate* over that array and compare each item, a word, to "the":

```
int count = 0;
for (String word : list1) {
   if (word.equals("the")) {
     count++;
   }
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are compering incorrect variable ''string[i]' with "the". Either rename your list1 as string or change your following two statement as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)

if (list1[i].equals("the"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answer to your **Edit**

Code will not compile successfully because

```
String[] list1 = list.split(" "); //here list is String[]
```

> [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. You can not call on array of String[]

You have `String[] list`, want to check string "the" in given string array, then simply use [ArrayUtils#contains()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
public static boolean contains(Object[] array,
                           Object objectToFind)
```

Checks if the object is in the given array.

The method returns false if a null array is passed in.

**Parameters:**
array - the array to search through
objectToFind - the object to find

**Returns:**
true if the array contains the object

Using `ArrayUtils` class you need jar to download. You can download from [this link](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils)

You also want to count the occurrence of string "the" in given string then you can use [StringUtils#countMatches(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
public static int countMatches(String str,
                           String sub)
```

Counts how many times the substring appears in the larger String.

A null or empty ("") String input returns 0.

```
StringUtils.countMatches(null, *)       = 0
StringUtils.countMatches("", *)         = 0
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", null)  = 0
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "")    = 0
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "a")   = 2
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "ab")  = 1
StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "xxx") = 0
```

**Parameters:**
str - the String to check, may be null
sub - the substring to count, may be null

**Returns:**
the number of occurrences, 0 if either String is null

Click [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils) to get the jar for `StringUtils` class

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it

- Use below code

  ```
  String str = "abc the def the ghi the";
  String find = "the";

  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while(str.indexOf(find, i) != -1) {
      count++;
      i = str.indexOf(find, i) + find.length();
  }
  System.out.println(count);
  ```
- if you want to use apache commons lang library[org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils] then you can do somethig like

  ```
  String str = "abc the def the ghi the";
  String find = "the";
  int count = StringUtils.countMatches(str, find)
  System.out.println(count);
  ```